# Spark Docker - Can't access web UI for resource manager - Mac PC

Tags: user-interface, hadoop, apache-spark, docker, hadoop-yarn

Can't access resource manager web ui - Spark docker container - Mac PC

These are the steps that I did:

docker pull sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0

docker run -it -p 8088:8088 -p 8042:8042 -p 4040:4040 -h sandbox sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0 bash

I tested using this: ( Runs fine )

## run the spark shell

spark-shell \
--master yarn-client \
--driver-memory 1g \
--executor-memory 1g \
--executor-cores 1

## execute the the following command which should return 1000

scala> sc.parallelize(1 to 1000).count()

But can't access the web ui:

I tried:

a. :8088

b: http://sandbox:8088/proxy/application_1458858022274_0002/A

c: localhost:8088

Nothing works.. Any help ??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you on MacOs, Windows or Linux?

Comment: Can you see the Spark UI at port 4040?

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the ports before publishing them. Either `EXPOSE 8088 8042 4040` in the Dockerfile or `-e 8088 -e 8042 -e 4040` in your run command. Expose functionality is separated from publish/host mapping functionality because there are cases where one would like to expose to port to other containers without mapping it to the host.

Comment: If you modify the Dockerfile, you need to rebuild the image. If you use `-e`, you should see the result immediately.

Comment: I didn't modify the docker file.. I am using a Mac PC.. problem may be specific to that